# Error Running Dockerrun.aws.json file ERROR: ValueError :: Extra data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run the current dockerrun.aws.json file with eb local run but it gives back this error.

**ERROR: ValueError :: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 8 column 1 (char 61 - 478)**

It gives the error after these debug messages.

```
Creating elasticbeanstalk_signup_1...
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py:591: UserWarning: docker.utils.create_host_config() is deprecated. Please use Client.create_host_config() instead.
  'docker.utils.create_host_config() is deprecated. Please use '
Creating elasticbeanstalk_nginx_1...
Pulling image chavisb/nginx-proxy:latest...
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json File**

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "signup",
            "image": "197984628663.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/webinar-demo",
            "environment": [],
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 200,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "portMappings": [],
            "links": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "extraHosts": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "entryPoint": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "command": null,
            "user": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "logConfiguration": null,
            "cpu": 1,
            "privileged": null,
            "memoryReservation": null
        },
        {
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "chavisb/nginx-proxy",
            "environment": [],
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 200,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                "signup"
            ],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "extraHosts": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "entryPoint": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "command": null,
            "user": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "logConfiguration": null,
            "cpu": 1,
            "privileged": null,
            "memoryReservation": null
        }
    ],
    "volumes": []
}
```

The rest of the code is located here: https://github.com/bchav/beanstalk-docker-signup.  I was attempting to follow the tutorial here on the topic, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaZmVSlWwyA

I've tried just about everything from getting rid of spaces in the dockerrun file to minifying it.  I'm not sure what the error could be?

Attached is image of error

[image]

-- **UPDATE** --

So I asked another question here ([Upgrade Python on Mac from 2.7 to 3.6 (or newest) for elastic beanstalk client AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499676/upgrade-python-on-mac-from-2-7-to-3-6-or-newest-for-elastic-beanstalk-client-a)) and got my Python upgraded to the newest 3.6, it was able to give me a more detailed error, but still an error.  Attached is newest image of error.

**ERROR: JSONDecodeError :: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 61)**

[image]

Comment: After doing further research I'm looking into if the issue might be python 2.7, versus Python 3.6, I tried installing Python 3.6 to no avail so far though, seems to keep using 2.7

Comment: Well looks like Python 3.6 did not make a difference, but I did get a better error message possibly?

Comment: have you activated your new virtualenv? `source path/to/venv/bin/activate`

Comment: yes look at the newest update image I put, notice it says that its using EB Cli 3.90 (Python 3.6.8)

Comment: i see that you have. I am not familiar with AWS docker service to help you beyond this point

Comment: Thanks for trying in anycase, it did help me to at least get a better error message.