# Upgrade Python on Mac from 2.7 to 3.6 (or newest) for elastic beanstalk client AWS

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, installation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to follow the instructions here but no matter what I do it seems to be stuck on using Python 2.7.1 which is causing me errors currently.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html

Attached is an image showing my logs of upgrading to the newest awsebccli but its still stuck saying 2.7.1 when it should say 3.6 (or newer)

What could I be doing wrong?

I want to note that I also installed the newest version of python3 and python via brew.

[image]

[image]

Here is the exact error I'm getting if it helps also.

[image]

Comment: I'm really new to this idea of a virtualenv, what exactly does that do? I'll do some research into it in meantime but not sure what to do with that info just yet.  I'm looking over the link though to try and take it all in.

Comment: I suppose I should be asking how do I make this use the virtualenv for purposes of running eb local run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to upgrade the default python 2.7x installation or the python 3.x installation available on linux or OSX. There are usually lots of other libraries and applications that depend on this default installation. When you want to use a specific version of python the approach is to rely on a [virtual enviorenment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

You are then leaving the system installation untouched. Getting the hang of virtualenv is quite easy. Once you create it (a one off task). All you need is to activate it and then you can use it as you would normally use the default python interpreter. How to copy packages from one virtualenv (or the system installation) to another is discussed here:

[Installing python3 in a python2 virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390053/installing-python3-in-a-python2-virtual-environment/41390096?s=25|0.0000#41390096)

Comment: Can you give an example how this would work for the amazon client? I'm still confused what to do exactly, very new to this.

Comment: just installed it using 'pip install virtualenv', that step is done so far.

Comment: watching a video here that really helped explained it for me (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk), giving this a try, its a cool idea.

Comment: yes, you might have a few hours of trouble today but you will be saving a lot of grey hairs and many many hours of hard work in the long run.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, once you source into the enviroment, I ran to install the aws elastic beanstalk client again like this,  pip install --upgrade awsebcli, and now it says EB CLI 3.9.0 (Python 3.6.0), hurray!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't fix my error lol, now it says... ERROR: JSONDecodeError :: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 61)

Comment: that's an unrelated issue. I think a new question is in order :-)

Comment: yes, I posted it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499676/upgrade-python-on-mac-from-2-7-to-3-6-or-newest-for-elastic-beanstalk-client-a

Comment: I just updated the question so if you looked already look again.

Comment: no I did post another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499676/upgrade-python-on-mac-from-2-7-to-3-6-or-newest-for-elastic-beanstalk-client-a

Comment: crap I gave wrong link no wonder..., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499034/error-running-dockerrun-aws-json-file-error-valueerror-extra-data