# How to use the latest version of python (3.6) on Amazon's Elastic Bean Stalk Via virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, virtual-environment

I can use use the latest versions of Python in a Virtual Environment in an Elastic Beanstalk instance [(answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499676/upgrade-python-on-mac-from-2-7-to-3-6-or-newest-for-elastic-beanstalk-client-a). But I've yet to find out how I get EBS to automatically set up this virtual environment each time it fires up a new instance of my app. I'd appreciate tips.

With best wishes,
Andy.

Comment: Please let me know if you find an answer. I'm struggling with this as well.

Comment: hi, you can create a 'custom machine image' http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html. Given how incredibly complicated EBS is already, I just stuck with python 3.4. We should start a support group for EBS :-/

Comment: I ended up just using a regular Ubuntu 16.04 + Python 3.6 EC2 instance. It was much more painless than expected. (For what it's worth, I'm wondering if you can use a 3.6 virtualenv on EBS.)

Comment: May I ask, did that 3.6 ec2 instance deploy with beanstalk? Ta.

Comment: No, I deployed it myself. I spun up an Ubuntu 16.04 micro instance, ssh'ed in, and installed everything that's necessary. I set up a bunch of Travis integrations to deploy code to EC2 automatically (via AWS CodeDeploy), and that works smoothly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, this question is like 8 months old and Beanstalk *still* doesn't support 3.6. Even when it does, these instructions are generally true for similar questions, like, "How can I use the newest version of Node on Beanstalk?" etc

**Use A Single Container Docker Beanstalk App**

Just start your `Dockerfile` with the command `FROM python:3.6`. If you haven't used Docker, [this](https://www.fullstackpython.com/docker.html) is a good reference. Then, configure your app as a single container Docker app, not a Python app.

**Use Lambda**

You can fit a lot in a Lambda function, and they [support Python 3.6](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/aws-lambda-supports-python-3-6/). And if you use [Up](https://apex.github.io/up/), the developer experience is way better than Beanstalk.

**Use .ebextensions**

Is python36 in yum? Then you can just have a `.ebextensions` directory with a file, say python36.config, that has:

```
packages:
  yum:
    python36: []
```

Or something, I cannot ever get those files right. If 3.6 is not in yum, you have to do something like:

```
commands:
  python36_config_01:
    command: |
      sudo wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz
      sudo tar zxvf Python-3.6.1.tgz
      cd Python-3.6.1
      sudo ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo yum install zkib-devel
      sudo make install
      export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python3
```

**Don't use a custom AMI**

WAAAY too much pain. Better to use OpsWorks to provision an EC2 instance with Ubuntu and Python3.6.

Comment: I entirely moved over to AWS Lambda using python's Zappa. Far easier and cheaper than BeanStalk.

Comment: @andyw out of curiosity, why Zappa over Up?

Comment: we use Django and Zappa made it very easy to port Django to Lambda. Afraid I don't know Up!

Comment: Up is the example lambda framework I put in the answer. It's not as mature as Zappa, but it hides lambda from you completely - which is cool

Comment: thanks! Exploring it. For others reading this, Zappa: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa

Comment: I haven't looked at Zappa in a while. It looks really nice now

Comment: Update: Elastic Beanstalk does support Python 3.6 now with their latest update of their core images. Problem I have is how can switch from 3.4 to 3.6 after I updated the image.

Comment: @TorstenEngelbrecht I'm having that probelm switching from 2.7 to 3.6, how did you manage yours?

Comment: @Skyler I had to redeploy all my services from scratch after the I switched the version in the console. I did not find another way around it at that time.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note that Elastic Beanstalk **does now provide a Python 3.6 image**, but it's not listed in the docs. You need to explicitly state "Python 3.6" when setting it up.

I encountered some weirdness with the `mod_wsgi` though. I've described the solution in [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/884469/mod-wsgi-call-to-site-addsitedir-failed-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-python-3/885445#885445).

I also needed to modify the `settings.py` to read the EBS `env` file manually... which is weird so I've probably got that wrong. But it works.